# BOPF VALIDATIONS DOESN'T WORKING in cds views

Tags: abap, cds

i have created a bobf object in cds named /BOBF/IF_FRW_VALIDATION~EXECUTE
to use it for validation purpose i have tried following code to  stop updating the value using its export parameter eo_message.

```
   DATA: ls_message TYPE symsg.
   if lv_val = abap_false.
  ls_message-msgty ='E'.
  ls_message-msgid = 'SY'.
  ls_message-msgno = '005'.
  IF eo_message IS NOT BOUND.
    eo_message = /bobf/cl_frw_factory=>get_message( ).
  ENDIF.



  ET_FAILED_KEY = IT_KEY.
 APPEND VALUE #( key = ls_root-key ) TO et_failed_key.
  CALL METHOD eo_message->add_message
    EXPORTING
      is_msg = ls_message.
     endif.
```

but the update operation(for which i have created the bobf) is still being performed

Comment: what is "lv_val“ for?

Comment: lv_val is a flag variable ,when lv_val is false then i have to raise exception else do nothing (as cds will update it automatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in bobf validations object click on  "trigger configuration" of your corresponding implementation class there  i had to select on 'check before save' and also select checkbox of   the check field along with update field.